# Methods to find the relationships between independent and dependent variables instead of regression

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression

Which statistical method can be used to find the relationships between independent and dependent variables instead of regression? And their advantages over regression.
It should be mentioned I am not able to do regression due to less number of observations that I have 5 independent variables 3 categorical and two continuous.

Comment: re: "I am not able to do regression due to less number of observations that I have 5 independent variables": does this mean you have more predictors than you have samples? So, your sample size is less than $5$?

Comment: @macro: my observation is 21 and my variables are 5.my complete question is my previous question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29612/minimum-number-of-observations-for-multiple-linear-regression

Answer (score 2):

In that case, the best approach is to do a linear model with the 5 variables. If you know R, you put them in a `data.frame` that you call `data`, the "independent" variable in the first column and the other ones after, the individual observation in each line and you do:

```
anova(lm(data))
```

To me that's the best use you can make of your precious data points. If you have too few, no statistical method will save you.