# Choosing between feature selection and regularization to overcome over-fitting in categorical regression

Tags: regression, feature-selection, regularization, overfitting

In order to overcome over-fitting during a regression process over categorical features, one can either

1) Apply L1/L2/Elastic regularization during the regression, for example as answered here

[When to use regularization methods for regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/when-to-use-regularization-methods-for-regression)

2) Filter out categories which appear less than X times, where X is at least 10-20 ,for example

[Minimum number of observations for multiple linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29612/minimum-number-of-observations-for-multiple-linear-regression)

The advantage in method 2 is that I can set with this rule of thumb approach the value of X to be 10-20, while the regularization method requires a costly computational cross validation step to be able to choose properly the correct regularization parameter, which would in fact multiply the regression running time by a factor. In addition, it greatly reduces the number of features when the categories have a long tail distribution - This can mean a big decrease in running time and memory consumption.

What is the common practice? When should I prefer one method over the other? Is the second method an acceptable one, or is the correct way to always perform some sort of regularization?